# not able to install easyocr (pytorch error)

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to install easyocr for python using pip

```
pip install easyocr
```

but it's not installing

its givig me this in the terminal

```
ERROR: torchvision 0.5.0 has requirement torch==1.4.0, but you'll have torch 0.1.2.post2 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: torch, torchvision, python-bidi, scipy, cycler, kiwisolver, python-dateutil, certifi, pyparsing, matplotlib, PyWavelets, imageio, decorator, networkx, tifffile, scikit-image, easyocr
  Running setup.py install for torch ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Murari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jl3470hv\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Murari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jl3470hv\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8j183bzh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jl3470hv\torch\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jl3470hv\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jl3470hv\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jl3470hv\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\murari\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Murari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jl3470hv\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Murari\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jl3470hv\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Murari\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-8j183bzh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.2.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and finally fixed it by creating the environment.

Here is the code.

```
!conda create -n easyocr python=3.8

!conda activate easyocr

pip install easyocr
```

If the issue got resolved, please vote for the answer.